# Run apps/Display long texts on ipod nano?

Tags: ipod

Is it possible to run custom apps or display long text on an ipod nano or a device that's similar to it?

Comment: Please define "long text" and "similar to it" so your question can be precisely answered.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that by long text, you mean syncing notes or other text to be read on the iPod. The current generation iPod Nano doesn't contain a notes application, nor does it support apps. There was some news a while back that someone managed to do some hacking on it, but as of now, I haven't heard anything. The iPod Touch would do better for notes and apps than the iPod Nano.

Comment: Prefer pebble...